# How to fix "Kibana server is not ready yet" error when using AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kibana, azure-aks, kubernetes-helm

I'm setting up ELK services in Azure Kubernetes Service. But I only see this error:

> "Kibana server is not ready yet"

I'm using Helm to install the stable/elastic-stack release without any changes (default for everything) in AKS.

```
helm install --name elk stable/elastic-stack
```

And I also added an ingress controller to expose the Kibana server to public.
However, I only see "Kibana server is not ready yet" error.

I've checked the Kibana pod is running, as well as the ElasticSearch. As a newbie in Kubernetes, I have no idea about how to find the error log in Kibana instance. Can anyone help me on this? It is also appreciated if you can indicate what step I am missing.

Comment: You should check if all the services and pods in the running state. Maybe the resource is not enough for all the services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you didn't change the value for `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` environment variable in Kibana deployment with your original one, as it was shipped with default values from `Elastic-stack` Helm chart. Therefore, you have to replace [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started.html) URL with actual service address inside Kibana configuration.

You can do it in a two ways:

- Update the value within Helm Chart:

  `helm upgrade -f new-values.yml {release name} {package name or path}`

The default `values.yaml` for `Elastic-stack` Helm chart can be found [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/elastic-stack/values.yaml). Also might be useful to get more details in the official Helm [documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-upgrade).

- Replace `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` environment variable in the related to
  Kibana deployment:

  `kubectl edit deployment elk-kibana`

  `kubectl delete pod <elk-kibana-Pod-name>`

Wait until Kubernetes successfully terminates the old and spin up a new Kibana Pod.

Comment: Yes, you are right. After updating the ELASTICSEARCH_URL to the Service name, I'm able to see the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might be the version incompatible issue. Just follow the console to get the errors.
Kibana version should be always higher than Elasticsearch.In that case, it gives an error following.

[error][status][plugin:xpack_main@7.4.0] Status changed from yellow to red - This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v7.4.0 on all nodes. I found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: v7.1.1 @ 127.0.0.1:9200 (127.0.0.1)